# Executing queries in KDB database using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, kdb

I am able to execute the following code to select all the data from the table :-

```
package com.jdbc;
import java.sql.*;
//in kdb+3.x and above
//init table with
//\p 5001
//Employees:([]id:0 1 2;firstName:`Charlie`Arthur`Simon;lastName:`Skelton`Whitney`Garland;age:10 20 30;timestamp:.z.p+til 3)
public class Selection{

  static final String JDBC_DRIVER="jdbc";
  static final String DB_URL="jdbc:q:localhost:5001";
  static final String USER="";
  static final String PASS="";
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    try{
      Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt=conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id, firstName, lastName, age,timestamp FROM Employees");
      while(rs.next()){
        long id=rs.getLong("id");
        long age=rs.getLong("age");
        String first=rs.getString("firstName");
        String last=rs.getString("lastName");
        Timestamp timestamp=rs.getTimestamp("timestamp");
        System.out.print("ID: "+id);
        System.out.print(", Age: "+age);
        System.out.print(", FirstName: "+first);
        System.out.println(", LastName: "+last);
        System.out.println(", Timestamp: "+timestamp);
      }
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
      se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
      try{
        if(stmt!=null)
          stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
        if(conn!=null)
          conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But whenever I try to run other queries, then the code gives me error, for example, for the following code :-

```
package com.jdbc;
import java.sql.*;

//in kdb+3.x and above
//init table with
//\p 5001
//Employees:([]id:0 1 2;firstName:`Charlie`Arthur`Simon;lastName:`Skelton`Whitney`Garland;age:10 20 30;timestamp:.z.p+til 3)

public class Insertion {

  static final String JDBC_DRIVER="jdbc";
  static final String DB_URL="jdbc:q:localhost:5001";
  static final String USER="";
  static final String PASS="";

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    try{
      Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt=conn.createStatement();
      stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(9, 10, 'X', 'Y', " + new java.sql.Timestamp(0) + ")");

      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
      se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
      try{
        if(stmt!=null)
          stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
        if(conn!=null)
          conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For this code, I get the following error :-

> Connecting to database... Creating statement... java.sql.SQLException:
>     at jdbc.q(jdbc.java:22)     at jdbc$co.ex(jdbc.java:26)     at
>   jdbc$st.executeUpdate(jdbc.java:89)   at
>   com.jdbc.Insertion.main(Insertion.java:27)

Evn when I try selection queries with aggregation functions, I use to get similar error. To summarize, I am able to do only simple selection of data and nothing else.

Any clues ?

Are there any study ;links on how to use JDBC for making complex queries on KDB database ?

I tried using prepared statements too (code is as follows), but still, no luck :-

```
package com.jdbc;
import java.sql.*;

//in kdb+3.x and above
//init table with
//\p 5001
//Employees:([]id:0 1 2;firstName:`Charlie`Arthur`Simon;lastName:`Skelton`Whitney`Garland;age:10 20 30;timestamp:.z.p+til 3)

public class Insertion {

  static final String JDBC_DRIVER="jdbc";
  static final String DB_URL="jdbc:q:localhost:5001";
  static final String USER="";
  static final String PASS="";

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement stmt=null;
    try{
      Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt=conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Employees(id,firstName,lastName,age,timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  stmt.setInt(1, 10);
  stmt.setString(2, "X");
  stmt.setString(3, "Y");
  stmt.setInt(4, 5);
  stmt.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(0));
      stmt.executeUpdate();

      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
      se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
      try{
        if(stmt!=null)
          stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
        if(conn!=null)
          conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: I used that as well, still the same error encountered.

Comment: Then post your new code. Hint: if there is no '?' in your SQL query, and if you don't call setXxx() on your prepared statement, you're not doing it right.

Comment: Updated the post to include the code.

Comment: The correct syntax for an insert statement is `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...)`

Comment: Oops, my bad. I have updated the corrected code. I have tried to execute that as well, but the error still remains the same.

Comment: And the error doesn't come without any error message? Post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: It is the complete stack trace.

Comment: I have no idea. I've never heard of that database you're using, but the fact that it doesn't provide any error message with its exceptions makes me think you probably should use another one.

Comment: @JB Nizet Although not the most user-friendly, KDB (http://kx.com) is highly popular in financial/trading platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the native API rather than JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same INSERT problem. By pure chance, found that if you change 'VALUES' to the lower-case 'values' , then *static* INSERT statement starts to work. Still have no luck with PreparedStatement execution though. (In my case, using native API in not an option, unfortunately.)